# Convert the given Moore Machine into Mealy machine

Tags: computer-science, solution, automata, finite-automata

[Convert the given Moore Machine into Mealy machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS1rT.png)

I'm currently working on converting a Moore Machine into a Mealy machine, and I'm uncertain about the correctness of my solution. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me in validating my approach and provide guidance if needed. Your expertise in this matter would be invaluable to me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is transition table of Given  Moore Machine.

- In Moore Machine output is related to state.
- In Mealy Machine output is related to edge.

[image]

This is transition table of Mealy Machine for given Moore Machine.

In Mealy Machine you can reach to same state with the different outputs, in Moore Machine you can not because output is related to state in Moore Machine.

It is easy convert Moore -> Mealy compare to Mealy -> Moore

[image]